# Windows WSL: systemctl restart chatwoot.target not working

Tags: ruby, chat, chatwoot

I have installed chatwoot from https://www.chatwoot.com/docs/self-hosted/deployment/linux-vm but it's not working & getting the following error.

The system has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1).

Comment: Use `service <service_name> <action>` as `root` user (ie. `service chatwoot.target restart`). Also, consider posting this kind of question on https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Sumak it is not working as chatwoot.target. getting following response




`root@DESKTOP-UG2AOTV:/home/rohit# service chatwoot.target restart
chatwoot.target: unrecognized service
root@DESKTOP-UG2AOTV:/home/rohit# sudo service chatwoot.target restart
chatwoot.target: unrecognized service`

Comment: Can you please share the output of `service --status-all | grep chat` ?